# Differentiability of the composition of a Lipschitz, convex function and a power function

Tags: analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

$f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a positive, convex and Lipschitz function.

Is the fuction $|f|^{2+\alpha}$, $\alpha>0$, twice continuously differentiable?

How to prove it, or there is some counterexample?

Comment: To be more precise, $n>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: Let $f(x) = |x| + 1.$ Then $f:\mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {R}$ is convex and Lipschitz. But $|f(x)|^3 = f(x)^3 = |x|^3 + 3x^2 + 3|x| +1,$ which implies $|f|^3$ is not differentiable at $0.$

Comment: Sorry, I should say that n>1.

Comment: How do you define a convex function from $\mathbb {R}^n$ to $\mathbb {R}^n$?

Comment: Sorry again, the condition is modified, could you consider it again, thx.